# Pattern match "LIKE" and escape special character with Python postgres?

Tags: python, postgresql, pattern-matching

How to pattern match "LIKE" and escape special character with the below Python code? I'm getting errors with special characters.

"parameter" values are "1.1", "1.2","1.3"

```
cr.execute("select sequence from account_stock_info "
"where sequence like '%s.%' "
"order by sequence ",
(tuple(parameter)))
```

Original query on PGADMIN was:

```
select sequence from account_stock_info
where sequence like '1.1.%'
order by sequence
```

Answer:"1.1.1", "1.1.1.03", "1.1.2","1.1.2.04","1.1.3"

Please help with Python pattern match.

Answer (score 1):

First error is using `tuple` function with string parameter:

```
>>> tuple('1.1')
('1', '.', '1')
```

you can pass tuple explicitly: `(parameter,)` or use dict to pass parameters.

To pass percent sign to `LIKE` statement you can add additional percent sign in your query:

```
parameter = "1.1"
cr.execute("select sequence from account_stock_info "
           "where sequence like '%s.%%' "
           "order by sequence ",
           (parameter,))
```

or pass it in parameter (quotes can be deleted here):

```
parameter = "1.1.%"
# ...
"where sequence like %s "
```

Comment: Do you have more complete sql query? I still have problem with passing parameters in Like statement?

Comment: I got error. My code:     parameter = "1.1.%"
            cr.execute("select id,name,sequence from account_stock_info "
                       "where sequence like %s "
                       "order by sequence ",
                       (parameter,))     Error:  No operator matches the given name and argument type(s). You might need to add explicit type casts.
, in query select id,name,sequence from account_cash_move_type where sequence like %s order by sequence

Comment: I got error. It seems "sequence" is reserved word in Postgre. How to use sequence column now?